# line 7, in <module> if a[1]**a[2]>b[1]**b[2]: IndexError: list index out of range в чем проблема

Tags: python, list

Объясните пожалуйста, в чем суть ошибки?

```
x=list(map(str, input().split()))
a=[]
b=[]
a=list(map(str, x[1].split('^')))
b=list(map(str, x[2].split('^')))
if a[1]**a[2]>b[1]**b[2]:
 print(x[1])
elif a[1]**a[2]<b[1]**b[2]:
 print(x[2])
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\misha\Desktop\Новая папка\aaa.py", line 7, in 
>       if a[1]**a[2]>b[1]**b[2]: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Что должен делать этот код?

Comment: Эта ошибка значит что вы обращаетесь к несуществующему элементу массива

Answer (score 1):

Строки индексируются значениями от 0. Поэтому, если хотите взять второй элемент, надо брать индекс 1. Этот код сравнивает две степени, заданные во входном потоке.

Далее - a и b массивы текста, а возводить в степень можно только числа.

```
a=[]
b=[]
a=list(map(int,x[0].split('^')))
b=list(map(int,x[1].split('^')))
if a[0]**a[1]>b[0]**b[1]:
 print(x[0])
elif a[0]**a[1]<b[0]**b[1]:
 print(x[1])
```